# How to Override a Property without marked like Partial, abstract or extern in the Base Property?

Tags: c#, class, inheritance, properties, overriding

I'm having a Property in the Remote Server named `HasChar` of the type `Bool`. I need to redefine it in my Derived class with some modification. But the Base Property didn't marked as `Partial`, `abstract` or `extern`. But I need to Redefine, How can I achieve? In the Derived Class, I need to access the `HasChar` Property of Base Class in the Derived Class, if the value is `False`, then I have to make the `BlogText` as `String.Empty`

> **Note**: The Base Class is in Remote Server, I Can't able to Change it or
>   initiate for the Changes. The Base Class Property don't marked as
>   `Partial`, `abstract` or `extern`. Don't create any additional property to achieve this. Kindly give the solution related to Override or similar.

My Base Class

```
public class BlogBase
{
    private string _blogText = string.Empty;
    public string BlogText 
    { 
        get { return _blogText; }; 
        set 
        {
            _blogText = value;
            HasChar = _blogText.Length >0 ? true : false;
        } 
    }

    public bool HasChar { get; set; }

}
```

My Derived Class : Rough Code

```
public class BlogChild : BlogBase
{
    private bool _hasChar = false;
    public bool HasChar 
    { 
        get { return _hasChar; }; 
        set 
        {
            _hasChar = value;
            if(!_hasChar)
                BlogText = string.Empty;
        } 
    }

}
```

Comment: Try to mark property with "new" keyword, or make some wrapper and work with it

Comment: @Alex I Can't able to change the Base Class, kindly review the Note.

Comment: @CodeCaster - I Showed you the Sample Code. I Can't able to explain the whole project. I need the requirement as mentioned as like above. If you understand the requirement, then give you answer, otherwise don't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hide the original property with the `new` keyword.

```
public new bool HasChar
{
    private bool _hasChar;
    get { return _hasChar; }
    set
    {
         // do other stuff
         _hasChar = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Kindly review the requirement. Then post the answer please.

Comment: Which requirement did I miss?

Comment: You Check the Derived Class Functionality as well as Note.

Comment: Edited the answer. You propably don't need to access the base class property so that should work.